# Got stuck when installing visual studio with xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

When I'm installing visual studio with xamarin it gets stuck like you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McTtq.jpg). I've waited for more than 3 hours but it still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. I canceled the installation. Rebooted my computer.
Then I restarted the installation. It installed correctly the second time. But
you need to be patient because it can take a long time to install. Especially if you are installing a lot of the optional packages. My OS is Windows 10. Hope this works for you.